# how can I style this php into rows of thumbnails with text under them?

Tags: php, html, css, format

So I'm trying to style this php with divs but it's not behaving how I'd like. I would like each thumbnail to have the catalog number appear under it. What's the best way to do this? I'm not super clear on how php and css interact yet.

```
 $records = $result->getRecords();

                foreach ($records as $record){
                    $photo = $record->getField("Photo");
                    $thumbnail = $record->getField("Thumbnail");
                    $cNum = $record->getField("Catalog_Number");


                    echo("<div id=\"image_catalog">"\);
                    echo ("<a href = \"");

                    echo ($photo);
                    echo ("\">");
                    echo ("<img src= \" ");
                    echo ($thumbnail);
                    echo (" \"></a>");

                    echo ("<font color=\"white\">");
                    echo ($cNum);
                    echo ("</font>");
                    echo ("</div>");
```

Comment: please provide your stylesheet

Comment: FYI, PHP and CSS never interact directly. PHP can create HTML which can reference the CSS.

Comment: thank you for that note, I hadn't thought of it that way.

Comment: Why did I lose two points on this question? How could I improve? I'm new to coding and the community. Any insight would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way for your code is to use the Heredoc Syntax.

```
echo <<<CATALOGUE
  <figure id="image_catalog">
    <a href="$photo"><img src="$thumbnail" /></a>
    <figcaption>$cNum</figcaption>
  </figure>
CATALOGUE; // No white space before Catalogue
```

Comment: I am researching Heredoc. Your code makes sense but I can't get it to do what I need. Thank you